# Raspberry Pi as HDMI to USB converter for HD Camcorder

Tags: usb, camera, hdmi, webcam

I know this is a long shot, but is it possible to use the HDMI port of the Raspberry Pi as an input from an HD camcorder, and use a USB port as an output for another device (like a laptop) to use as a webcam, like for Facebook Live?  The end result would be a device that does the same operation as this: [https://www.amazon.com/Elgato-Cam-Link-streaming-recording/dp/B0748QYPX9/ref=sr_1_4?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1505443816&sr=1-4&keywords=hdmi+to+usb+webcam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0748QYPX9)

HD Webcam --HDMI--> RPi --USB--> Laptop (Facebook Live)

Comment: The HDMI port on the Pi is strictly output only as far as I am aware. However there are other methods of capturing footage using the Pi. You might find this [superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1118496/can-raspberry-pi-capture-hdmi-input) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry pi on HDMI is an OUTPUT, so, it won't be possible to use it to gather the data from the hdmi.

My approach to this will be use an hdmi usb recorder.